# why the integral without singularity does not converge

Tags: numerical-integration

Here is an integral

```
NIntegrate[1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 
 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1), {px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10}]
```

the integrant are all sufficiently small, but still MMA give a result and say the integral coverage too slow. I tried different method, none of them works.
I could not understand what causes it? How to modify the code?

Comment: Often one can ignore `NIntegrate::slwcon` if there are no other errors.  (So you left out an important component of the question.  You also left out the error message names, which are helpful to include because then people with similar problems can search the site for them.)

Answer (score 6):

This works well.

```
NIntegrate[1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1), 

{px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10},Method -> "CartesianRule"] // Timing
```

> {58.875, 2.84714}

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  what is the reason this method work?  Do you have some advice to speed up the integral?

Comment: @p.s. See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html for more details. No, I don't have any advice to speed up the integral. In my opinion, one minute doesn't last too long.

Answer (score 5):

Lowering the precision goal slightly from `6` to `5` (perhaps advisable in a high-dimensional integral) and increasing `MinRecursion` avoids both the `NIntegrate::slwcon` and `NIntegrate::eincr` warnings:

```
NIntegrate[
  1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1),
  {px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10},
  PrecisionGoal -> 5,
  MinRecursion -> 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {5.563214`, 2.8471463223061835`}  *)
```

*Update: Alternative*

FWIW, you can do an expensive (i.e., takes time) symbolic integration on one or two of the variables, followed by a numerical integration.  E.g, integrating over `{py, 0, 10}` symbolically first takes about as long as the above and needs no other special numerical processing.  The numerical advantage here is reducing the dimension of the integral.  (In fact, if you integrate over `qx` and then `py`, then the two-dimensional integral is quite fast and unproblematic; however, the symbolic integration takes about 17 seconds.)

```
NIntegrate[
  Evaluate@Integrate[
    1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1),
    {py, 0, 10}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < px < 10 && 0 < py < 10 && 0 < qx < 10 && 0 < qy < 10]
  , {px, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.173041`, 2.8471449687848587`}  *)
```

We also get the extra digit of accuracy @user64494 got.

*Update 2: Third try, inspired by Mariusz Iwaniuk*

There is a slight "spike" in the value of the integrand near the subspace `px == qx == qy`.  This might be why `NIntegrate` has trouble getting the error estimate to satisfy precision goals of 6 or more.  Some weak evidence is that feeding the subspace as an `"Exclusion"` with the `"LocalAdaptive"` method to `NIntegrate` gives a fairly quick solution agreeing with the other solutions to slightly more than six digits.

```
NIntegrate[
  1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1),
  {px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10},
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive", Exclusions -> {px == qx == qy}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.497589`, 2.8471576198024686`}  *)
```

Comment: A professional answer. Can you explain why  AccuracyGoal -> 5 doesn't work well here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks. `AccuracyGoal` sets a goal for the number of digits after the decimal point. When the result is `1`, then `Precision` and `Accuracy` are the same.  The corresponding `AccuracyGoal` for this integral would be about ``Accuracy[2.8471463223061835`5]`` or `4.54559`. (The precision and accuracy goals combine, so that the absolute error estimate should be less than the sum of the errors implied by the two goals, and the correspondence is not quite as simple as I describe.)

Comment: @Michael E2   Thanks. You guys are really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

About a 1 second.

```
NIntegrate[
  1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 1), 
  {px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] // Timing

(*{1.45313, 2.84718}*)
```

or:

```
NIntegrate[1/(px^2 + py^2 + 1)/((px - qx)^2 + (px - qy)^2 + 1)/(qx^2 + qy^2 + 
  1), {px, 0, 10}, {py, 0, 10}, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 10}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, MinRecursion -> 1, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
  "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.687526, 2.84731}*)
```

Comment: (+1) Nice.  Seems to underestimate the error, though.  Have to bump up the `PrecisionGoal` to get a comparable quality result, and then it's not really faster (or so it seems to me).

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk    Thanks.